# Android - LinearLayout в HorizontalScrollView

Tags: horizontalscrollview, android, android-linearlayout, java

В HorizontalScrollView есть 7 элементов LinearLayout. Каждый лэйаут должен занимать ширину, равную ширине экрана, но используя `fill_parent` всё равно результат не такой, какой ожидался: устанавливается непонятно какая ширина и видно другие лэйауты. Пожалуйста, помогите задать для лэйаутов одинаковую ширину.

Единственный выход, который я пока нашёл:
Определяем каждый лэйаут. Получаем ширину экрана. Через LayoutParams ставим значение для лэйаута.

Я пока не хочу писать такой костыль, вдруг вы подскажете способ полегче)

Comment: Покажите XML-разметку.

Comment: Она очень большая (800+ строк)

Comment: Ого. А как же `ViewStub`, `include` да `merge`? Ну да ладно. Покажите часть, относящуюся непосредственно к `HorizontalScrollView`.

Comment: а без разметки вам никто не поможет, вырезайте всё лишнее и...

Comment: `<ru.zein4.gbreak.DeepScrollView
   android:id="@+id/DeepScrollViewVIEW"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:scrollbars="none" >`

Из прошлого ответа немного переделал ваш код :)

Comment: попробуйте вместо LinearLayout использовать RelativeLayout

Comment: Пробовали добавить в каждый LinearLayout атрибут android:weight="1"?
Если это не поможет, могу посоветовать костыль поменьше =) Определить ширину экрана устройства и задать ширину HorizontalScrollView как ширинаЭкрана*7

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле это не костыль. Создайте свой класс, наследник от HorizontalScrollView, в конструкторе создайте нужное количество linearlayout, задайте ширину, добавьте в runtime. На самом деле это гибче.